# Earliest I can run xrandr?

Tags: gnome3, luks, xrandr, cryptsetup, brightness

Every time I boot my laptop I go blind. I can use `xrandr` to set the brightness but it becomes a rather impractical. I also use `LUKS` so when I boot the computer I am always greeted with (from what I think) cryptsetup.

Is there a way to run my desired xrandr command when I am asked for the encryption password? Otherwise, when is the earliest (from turning on the laptop) that I can do this and where/how should I configure this?

Amongst other stuff I have tried `rc.local`, `/etc/gdm3/Init/Display`, `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` but nothing seems to work. I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with Gnome and the command I try to run is `xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.3`.

**Some updates:**

Some more info on my hardware and what I have tried.

- I have the XPS 15 9550 which comes with Intel Skylake and a dedicated Nvidia graphics card. I have disabled the Nvidia card from the Nvidia X Server Settings GUI tool.
- I have only `intel_backlight` in `/sys/class/backlight` by default. I can edit the brightness from there between 0 and 12 but the brightness at 1 is still too bright.
- I have tried altering the `/etc/default/grub` to include `acpi_backlight=vendor`. That creates the entry `/sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight`. This gives some more control but it's very unstable (brightness jumping here and there and freezes).
- I have tried altering the `/etc/default/grub` to include `acpi_backlight=video`. That creates the entry `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` which permits more granularity (0-66). However the monitor still uses the intel_backlight. I tried to solve this by explicitly configuring the xorg.conf to use the ACPI backlight but to no vail.

Comment: `/etc/gdm3/Init/Display` Xorg must be running for use `xrandr`.

Comment: There is probably a non-X11 way to set the brightness. If you're running systemd, there is systemd-backlight. There should also be a file in /sys you can just use `echo` on.

Comment: If  ACPI interface is available you can create a udev-rule. `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-backlight.rules

# Set backlight level to 9
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="acpi_video0", ATTR{brightness}="9" `

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem is that without `xrandr` I can only set the value between 1 and 12, where all values are extremely bright. Only solution I have found until now to set the brightness below tha is to use xrandr.

Comment: What exact model of graphics card do you have? If you have two, which one does X use?

Comment: @Gilles I use the Intel GPU. I have updated my question with some more details..

Comment: Can you try kerneloption `video.use_bios_initial_backlight=1`